# How can jQuery be used to handle timer in click, dblclick separation

Tags: jquery, timer, click, double-click

I am using the jQueryFileTree at http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/58 and I want to distinguish between the dblclick and click events as a click is always triggered by a dblclick.

Googling about led to be a technique in which click is handled by a timer which kicks in when a dblclick does not cancel it.

Is there some way this can be used with jQuery and the jQuery example in an elegant manner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` to realize the timer functionality:

```
var timeout;
var delay = 500;  // Delay in milliseconds

$("...")
    .click(function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            // This inner function is called after the delay
            // to handle the 'click-only' event.
            alert('Click');
            timeout = null;
        }, delay)
    }
    .dblclick(function() {
        if (timeout) {
            // Clear the timeout since this is a double-click and we don't want
            // the 'click-only' code to run.
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = null;
        }
        // Double-click handling code goes here.
        alert('Double-click');
    }
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example

I am practising jquery and trying to bind it to elements of the jqueryfiletree.js. How would you bind a timer to a particular element, how would the timer know which element it is triggering for ?

The elements are file nodes and directories in the file tree.

Comment: @vfclists, you can see my answer to see how to bind a timer to a element.

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer, it doesn't work. While double clicking, the `Double-Click` alert comes first, closing which I find the `Click` alert waiting to be closed...

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Yes, it does not work.  A double click consists of two clicks, with the second one overriding the timeout here.  Please note that this snippet is just meant to transport the idea, not to provide a complete working example!  This site is about learning, not collecting ready-to-use recipes.

Comment: Yeah of course. Since I saw this to be the accepted answer, I thought that it may have worked for the OP. So I just confirmed that it doesn't...

Comment: Doesn't work, click event is triggered after dbl click.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Sparkle provides a clean elegant solution for this, by implementing a singleclick custom event. By doing this, you can use it just like any other event, so:

```
$('#el').singleclick(function(){});
// or event
$('#el').bind('singleclick', function(){});
```

It also provides custom events for the last and first clicks of a series of clicks. And the lastclick custom event actually passes the amount of clicks back! So you could do this!

```
$('#el').lastclick(function(event,clicks){
    if ( clicks === 3 ) alert('Tripple Click!');
});
```

You can find the appropriate demo showcasing what I've just said right [here](http://www.balupton.com/projects/jquery-sparkle/#event-singleclick) and the source code for defining the custom event right [here](http://github.com/balupton/jquery-sparkle/blob/9921fcbf1cbeab7a4f2f875a91cb8548f3f65721/scripts/resources/jquery.events.js#L256). It's open source under the AGPL licence, so you can feel free to grab what you need out of it worry free! :-) It's also actively developed on a day to day basis so you will never be short on support.

But most importantly it is a DRY Plugin/Effect Framework to allow you to develop plugins and extensions much more easily. So I hope this helps to achieve that goal!

Comment: i forked and made changes to use jquery 3.x. feel free to use it: https://github.com/jeffhongxiao/jquery-sparkle

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following code

```
$("#clickMe").click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('clicked')){
        alert("Double click");
        //here is your code for double click
        return;
    }else{
         $this.addClass('clicked');
        //your code for single click
         setTimeout(function() { 
                 $this.removeClass('clicked'); },500);
    }//end of else
});
```

Demo goes here http://jsfiddle.net/cB484/