# how to prevent the double mouse click(at a time)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".voteMe").one('click', function (event) { 
              event.preventDefault();          
           //my stuff

$(this).prop('disabled', true);
        });
    });
```

the above code is allowing single mouse click.but it is not allowing next click i mean next single mouse click it is assuming  double click. my final conclusion is i want allow all single clicks and dis allow double clicks(when ever consumer enter double click it will take only single click only)

Comment: this would be useful.... pls check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Just don't bind anything to the double-click event.

Answer (score 1):

Use following Code

```
 $(".voteMe").click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) return;
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
         setTimeout(function() { $(this).removeClass('clicked'); }, 500);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` function and prevent the execution of the handler in a specified period of time:

```
$(".voteMe").on('click', function (event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) return;

    var $this = $(this).addClass('clicked');
    setTimeout(function() { $this.removeClass('clicked'); }, 500);

    // ...
});
```

Comment: thanking you friend it is working fine.but some times it will allowing double click also my set timeout 1000

Comment: @user2750450 Well, this shouldn't happen logically, can you provide a demo?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".voteMe").one('click', function (event) { 
          event.preventDefault();          
       //my stuff

       $(this).prop('disabled', true);

       $(".voteMe").unbind("click");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should then unbind the double click:

```
$('.voteMe').unbind('dblclick');
```

Comment: The use of `one` is the reason he can only click once.

Comment: my bad, that's why i said I think, good to learn something new

Answer (score -2):

[Jquery bind double click and single click separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately)

var DELAY = 700,
    clicks = 0,
    timer = null;

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("a")
.live("click", function(e){

    clicks++;  //count clicks

    if(clicks === 1) {

        timer = setTimeout(function() {

            alert('Single Click'); //perform single-click action

            clicks = 0;  //after action performed, reset counter

        }, DELAY);

    } else {

        clearTimeout(timer);  //prevent single-click action

        alert('Double Click');  //perform double-click action

        clicks = 0;  //after action performed, reset counter
    }

})
.live("dblclick", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  //cancel system double-click event
});
```

});

Comment: why using removed method live()?

Comment: I don't get it, what should i see in your provided jsfiddle?

Comment: As you've shown in your code, jQuery recognises the double-click event.  There's no need for antiquated methods such as this.