# Why doesn't jquery bind click and double click events separately?

Tags: jquery, click, double-click

I've been trying to add separate click and double-click events to a span tag such as:

```
    $( document ).ready(function(){

    $("span").dblclick(function(){alert("b");});
    $("span").click(function(){alert("a");});

     });
```

After much (much!) headbanging, I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately).  To be honest, it seems a bit surprising that jquery doesn't do this automatically.  Can someone provide an example as to why a person wouldn't want them to be bound separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, jquery does bind them separately.

It also works correctly.

You have to use `console.log` since `alert` disturbs the code execution.

### What happens on a double click?

When you use `console.log` you'll get 2 `a` since a double click has 2 clicks

and 1 `b` since only a single double click.

### What happens on a single click?

Only `.click()` will be executed.

Comment: So, if I click once, that's the ONLY event that will register?  In other words, once clicked, jquery won't look for other non-single click events?

Comment: No, both will have registered.

Comment: That explains it!  In my "real" code, my alert was getting in the way.

Comment: yeah, that's true. You got it