# How to prevent recurring of the first callback function on single click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a script that differentiate single and double left clicks. Whereas dbl click is successfully detected and the assigned function  is triggered upon event, single clicks are detected successfully but the assigned function is repeated infinitely upon event.

I have changed the original script for event delegation for I need dynamically generated DOM elements to respond with same functions to those events. After this change single click triggers the function assigned endlessly.

```
    //single and double clicks

jQuery.fn.single_double_click = function(single_click_callback, double_click_callback, timeout) {
  return this.each(function(){
    var clicks = 0, self = this;

    //delegated one:
    jQuery('#subunitscontainer').on('click', jQuery(this), function(event){
        
    //non delegated one:
    //single click has no problem but dynamically generated dom
    //does not response to the event here.
    //jQuery(this).click(function(event){
      clicks++;
      if (clicks == 1) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          if(clicks == 1) {
            single_click_callback.call(self, event);
          } else {
            double_click_callback.call(self, event);
          }
          clicks = 0;
        }, timeout || 300);
      }
    });
  });
}
//end single and double clicks
```

[jsfiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/farukscan/a6GVr/1/)

Comment: Since you're using JQuery, I would like to point out that JQuery does have a [double-click](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) function. Also interesting is that JQuery suggests not adding the single click and double-click event handlers on the same object for some very good reasons. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i am trying to query database on single click for months or days of months and fetch related content, and trying to go through smaller units, to days, on double click on bigger units, month names. and also on double r-click reverse this behaviour.

Comment: You are not delegating event here `jQuery('#subunitscontainer').on('click', jQuery(this), function(event){...});` The selector parameter only accepts a string, not a jQuery object. Here, you are binding click event to `#subunitscontainer` element as many times as you have matched elements passed to your jQuery function

Comment: There is a working script on StackOverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7845282/1948211

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery bind double click and single click separately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately)

Comment: See there what i meant, with only one element matching selector `$('.days')`, alert() is fired only once: http://jsfiddle.net/a6GVr/3/

Comment: @dschazam i have looked that working script. it is ok except it does not work when the dynamically generated dom elements are clicked or dbl clicked. that is the second part i try to achieve.

Comment: @A. Wolff your fiddle seems not working.

Comment: i have changed it and it now works in my way. as this `$("#subunitscontainer").on("click", "p", function(e){`

from
`$("p").on("click", function(e){` anything buggy or kludgy.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farukscan/a6GVr/4/)