# How to change element text in jQuery, pause, and reset original text

Tags: jquery, timeout, delay

The HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="change">Old Text</a>
<a href="#" class="change">Old Text</a>
```

I want to change the "Text" with jQuery, delay two seconds and set it back to the original.  I've tried timeout and delay unsuccessfully.  The page has multipe items that have the same text "Add to cart", and switch to "Added", then back again.

The jQuery:

```
$('.change').html('first').delay(2000).html('second')
```

This fails.  It ignores the first, and skips right to the second

```
_x = $(this);
$(_x).html('New Text');
_t = setTimeout(function(){
    $(_x).html('Old Text');
},2000);
```

This works, if the user clicks and doesn't trigger another before the 2 second reset.  If someone clicks #1 and then clicks #2 before #1 has the text reset, it works on #2 but the text on #1 stays with the New Text.

I thought that since it's inside a function, that the timeout would be instantiated for each object with it's own instance of _t, but apparently not.

I'm not sure if it matters, but the elements are sometimes loaded dynamically, and the click binding is set accordingly

```
$(element).on('click','.change',function(_e) { ...
```

How can I handle this?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try using [jquery - $.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) which will loop through all elements. Also if you can create a jsfiddle it will be convenient to debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE** [March 04, 2017]

In response to [Wim Mertens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054346/how-to-change-element-text-in-jquery-pause-and-reset-original-text/29054540?noredirect=1#comment72269276_29054540) comment:

> *Unfortunately this doesn't work when you double click ...*

You could tweak the code to handle both `click` and `dblclick` events and return the same expected behavior.

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7845282/1055987) you could do:

```
var
  DELAY = 700,
  clicks = 0,
  timer = null,
  restoreText = function(target, oldText, newText) {
    target.html(newText); // set new text
    setTimeout(function() {
      target.html(oldText); // restore old text after n seconds
    }, 2000);
  }

$(".change").on("click", function(e) {
  clicks++; //count clicks
  var that = $(this); // $(".change")
  if (clicks === 1) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      // set new text and restore old one after n seconds
      // parameters : target, oldText, newText 
      restoreText(that, that.html(), "new text")
      clicks = 0; //after action performed, reset counter
    }, DELAY);
    return false
  }
  // double click otherwise
  clearTimeout(timer); //prevent single-click action
  // set new text and restore old one after n seconds
  // parameters : target, oldText, newText 
  restoreText(that, that.html(), "new text")
  clicks = 0; //after action performed, reset counter
}).on("dblclick", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //cancel system double-click event
});
```

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/03eqaubL/)**

---

[Original answer]

Try

```
// add a refresh button to image previews
$(".change").on("click", function () {
    var oldText = $(this).html();
    var that = $(this)
    $(this).html("new text");
    setTimeout(function () {
        that.html(oldText);
    }, 2000);
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n38kbrou/)**

**NOTE**: if the elements to *click* are dynamically created, then try `.on()` in its *delegated* form like :

```
$(".parentSelector").on("click", ".change", function () {
    // handler
});
```

Comment: This was the right answer, but not for the right reason - but it still finally clued me in to what was wrong.

The redeclaring the variables fixes it.  See the following example, same exact code for both examples, with the exception of the 'var' https://jsfiddle.net/5n9k47be/1/

Comment: @Mark : you have to declare the variables somewhere in your document. If you add `"use strict";` at the top of your jsfiddle, you will see that the first piece of code triggers the js error `ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable oldText` ... just because you omitted the `var` declaration. The second piece of code works as it should.

Comment: @JFK I was looking for a solution like this. Unfortunately this doesn't work when you double click (some people do that apparently :), the new text doesn't revert back to the old. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @JFK I was tinkering with this a bit more. If you click more than twice it still doesn't work (I guess for really impatient people :) so I thought to simplify it by adding and removing a class that sets pointer-events to none. Created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c253gmom/

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this I'd do this:

HTML:

```
<div class="change">Add to cart</div>
<div class="change">Add to cart</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var wait;
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $( ".change" ).click(function() {
        clearTimeout(wait);

        $(this).html("Added!");
        // Add item to cart

        wait = setTimeout(function(){ 
            $(".change").html("Add to cart");
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Of course I've used div tags instead of hyperlinks. [Demo here!](https://jsfiddle.net/7var4r49/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In your Second code, dont double-wrap:

```
_x = $(this);
_x.html('New Text');
_t = setTimeout(function(){
    _x.html('Old Text');
},2000);
```

in your first, if its called inside the click event callback Function, Start with $(this).html(.....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var newtext = "New Text";
$(document).on("click", ".change", function() {
$(this).map(function(i, el) {
  $(el).html(function(idx, html) {
     $(this).delay(2000, "html").queue("html", function() {
       $(this).html(html)
     });
     return html.replace(html, newtext)
  }).dequeue("html")
})
});
$("body").append("<a href=# class=change>Old Text</a>"
                + "\n<a href=# class=change>Old Text</a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```