# Add double click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, spectrumjs

I implemented [spectrum color picker](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/), and I am trying to add a double click event to the palettes. (The one that has the predefined colors, the class name is: `sp-thumb-el`.) I added the following code after [line 476](https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum/blob/master/spectrum.js#L476):

```
paletteContainer.on("dblclick", ".sp-thumb-el", function (){
    console.log("you Double Clicked");
});
```

And nothing happens when I double click. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

[Line 479 in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50j3hxcv/)

Comment: there is no error with your code , you have paletteContainer defined wrong , or you have a typo in sp-thumb-el class.  This code would work otherwise.  One thing you can check is the jquery version and make sure it is after .on() was added

Comment: It seems, the element you're trying to bind already has a single-click bound to it. So, if you try binding double click, it will just execue the single click twice. You may refer to this thread to make both of them work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to the comment I made above, you might want to try a hack like this:

```
       paletteContainer.on("click", ".sp-thumb-el", function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                            clicks++;
           if(clicks===2){
             console.log("you Double Clicked");
             clicks=0;
           } 
        });
```

The same is updated in your plunkr too..

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tired your JSFiddle you created, and it doesn't fully work. If you click once, then click again, (not 2 in a row necessarily,) then it thinks it was a double click.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you want to do something like this.**

```js
$("#btn").dblclick(function(){

  console.log("working fine");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" > double click it </button>
```

Comment: this is not the way the OP wanted , the example was using .on()

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were missing `https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js`.
Also, You need to remove your `spectrum.css` link and add the correct **https** version at `https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.css`

View the updated version @ https://jsfiddle.net/f72tscdj/

Hope this helps,
Sean

Comment: I don't think this is an answer. I think it should be a comment. Also, The spectrum.js is there. It's in the javascript section of the code.