# setTimeout works as expected but seInterval doesn't in click event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, settimeout, setinterval

When I was working on the problem of differentiating between on a single click and a double click on the same element in plain JavaScript (no JQuery), I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately) solution given by @Garland Pope and translated it to plain JavaScript:

```js
var numClicks = 0,
  interval = null,
  delay = 250;
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  numClicks++;
  if (numClicks === 1) {
    interval = setTimeout(function() {
      // Things to do on one click.
      console.log("Single Click");
      numClicks = 0;
    }, delay);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(interval);
    // Things to do on double click.
    console.log("Double Click");
    numClicks = 0;
  }
});
```

But when I changed the `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` to `setInterval` and `clearInterval` respectively I did not get the expected result. With `setTimeout`, for two clicks within the **"delay"** time, it logged "Double Click" and for single click within the **"delay"** time, it logged "Single Click" only **once**.

But  with `setInterval`, the same story goes with the double click. But, the difference comes with the single click. When I click once within the **"delay"** time, it logs "Single Click" but **many times** and **never stops**.
Which is not what I wanted.

Can anyone explain why this happened? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need setInterval here, it will break all logic.
setTimeout - its timer that calls function once.
setInterval - its timer that calls function every  seconds.

You make click, then application starts timer and waits. If no more clicks it will say 'single click'

Here example, that will workm but it emulate setTimeout function

```js
var numClicks = 0;
var interval = null;
var delay = 250;

document.addEventListener('click', function () {
++numClicks;

if (numClicks === 1) {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        clearInterval(interval);

        // Things to do on one click.
        console.log('Single Click');
        numClicks = 0;
        
    }, delay);
} else {
    clearInterval(interval);

    // Things to do on double click.
    console.log('Double Click');
    numClicks = 0;
}
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain "setTimeout - its timer that calls function once setInterval - its timer that calls function every seconds"?

Comment: Yes, I understood. Thanks!