# Click function working, but DoubleClick function not working - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have menu items click to open sub items and then double click to follow through to the link. Have tried a variety of different approaches but for some reason nothing's happening when double clicked.

```
 $( ".site-head .section-menu .mobile-sub-menu ul li .first-a" ).on('click', function(event) {
        $( ".sub-items" ).addClass('hiddenMenu');     
        $(this).parent().find('.sub-items').removeClass('hiddenMenu');
        event.preventDefault();
    }); 


    $(document).on('dblclick', '.first-a', function() {
        console.log("event fired");
        window.location.replace($(this).attr("href"));

    });
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: the standard solution that has been suggested doesn't work in this situation. The double click should direct to link and the first should prevent going to the link and execute some other function...

Comment: Have you looked at your console? The event is being triggered, but your call to window.location.replace() might have a problem.

Comment: This isn't related to an answer, but related to the fact this sounds like utterly horrible UI to me.

Comment: @KyleSposatoNothing is happening in the console unfortunately

Comment: Mixing "click" and "double-click" in a web application is doomed to failure and terrible for usability anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery bind double click and single click separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately)

Comment: Why can't you try dblclick event to that id or class instead of using $(document)

Answer (score 0):

When you make the first click, don't immediately call the method, instead set a timer that calls the original callback function in say ~0.75 seconds UNLESS you receive a second click. You're firing off an event and handling the first click, so when the second click comes through - it's a single click, not a 'dblclick'

Comment: @dreamkiller this is the standard solution for this problem, please read here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately/7845282#7845282

Comment: that solution doesn't help because I'm trying to follow through to the link on the double click. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help You..

**HTML Part**

```
<p ondblclick="myFunction()">Double-click this paragraph to trigger a function.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

**JQuery Part**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to bind both click and doubleclick events to the same element, but if you must do so, this previously accepted answer provides a perfect solution by using a counter to track # of clicks: [Jquery bind double click and single click separately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7845282/2052492)