# How can i unbind double click event on a div on which click is already bind?

Tags: jquery

```
 $('#id').bind("dblclick", function (event)
    {
    event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#id').unbind("click");
    $('#id').bind("click", function ()
    {
    #mycode
    });
```

here both double and single click is called.how can i make it to call single event at a time?

Comment: You mean you want a double-click to *not trigger* a normal single-click event?

Comment: not clear at all what behaviour you want. If don't want `dblclick` why is it being attached?

Comment: @charlietfl my work is on click event but double click harms the code.but i am unable to prevent dblclick as it fires single click and dblclick both.

Comment: did you try search SO? there are several answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472433/how-can-jquery-be-used-to-handle-timer-in-click-dblclick-separation